# How can I measure time more precisely in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel document with some VBA scripts.

I'm using 'Timer' to measure execution times of my code.

I am not able to measure how long it takes to add an entry to a Dictionary. The result is 0.

Are there more precise mechanisms available that allow me to measure how long this takes?

Comment: It really depends how accurate you want to get. If 100ths of a second is sufficient, you can use the built in `Timer` function which gives you the number of seconds since midnight, to the 100th of a second.

Comment: Considering your self-answer to this question I'm assuming you meant `Timer` instead of `Time`? Also, I think you could improve the question because "not very precise" doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the script you can add this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_frequency Lib "kernel32" _
      Alias "QueryPerformanceFrequency" ( _
      ByRef Frequency As Currency) _
      As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_time Lib "kernel32" _
      Alias "QueryPerformanceCounter" ( _
      ByRef Counter As Currency) _
      As Long
```

Then in your code you can get high precision time measurements like this...

```
' run this once
Dim per_second As Currency: get_frequency per_second

' ...

' get start time
Dim t0 As Currency: get_time t0

' HERE perform the operations you want to time 
' ...

' get end time
Dim t1 As Currency: get_time t1

' calculate high precision duration
Dim elapsed_millis As Double: elapsed_millis = (t1 - t0) / per_second * 1000#
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the start of your subroutine:

```
Dim StartTime As Double 'Declaration of timer to identify length of runtime
StartTime = Timer
```

At this at the end of your subroutine:

```
Debug.Print "RunTime for Program is: " & Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, 
"hh:mm:ss.ms") 'Print out runtime for subroutine
```